# How to save an inner join to a new table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to save an inner join to a new table however it endlessly runs and eventually times out. The inner join itself works after about 15 seconds without creating a table.

Example:

```
create table newtable as(
SELECT thing1, thing2
FROM (container
INNER JOIN staff ON container.Staff = staff.name)
);
```

Example that works without creating the table:

```
SELECT thing1, thing2
    FROM (container
    INNER JOIN staff ON container.Staff = staff.name);
```

Comment: You should mention the database system that you use.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `join`, it will start returning results before all the results have generated.

When you do the `create table`, you must wait until *all* the results have been generated.

It is likely that you have a lot of results.  You can get an estimate of how many by doing:

```
select count(*), count(distinct staff)
from container;

select count(*), count(distinct name)
from staff;
```

And then:

```
select sum(c.cnt * s.cnt)
from (select staff, count(*) as cnt
      from container
      group by staff
     ) c join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from staff
      group by name
     ) s
     on c.staff = s.name;
```

This is the number of rows that need to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have tried like this and it didnt work ?

```
create table newtable as  
SELECT thing1, thing2 
FROM  container 
INNER JOIN staff  
ON container.Staff = staff.name
```

How large are the tables ? When you run a query from a client program usually only the first few rows are fetched, so that you will not need to wait for everything to download, but when you execute a create table, it has to be created in its entirety, and if you have *millions of rows ...*

Comment: There are 240,000 rows for the specific table but  the original table without the join can be created in about 20 seconds so surely it wouldn't too long. I ran it for 20 minutes and still doesn't return anything